# JSP submit a textbox value

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, database, jsp

[image]

I want to insert my textbox value ("20") into the database. How do I do it ? And if the user never put in any value in the textbox, it will notify the user.

I have create a js file but it doesn't work...

**assign.js**

```
document.getElementById("assignBtn").onclick = function () {
    var errmessage = "";
    var na = document.forms["assignTo"]["Number"].value;
    if (na == "") {
        //if(document.getElementById("ExerciseArm").value=="") {
        errmessage += "*Please enter the number of time for arm<br>";
    }
    var nl = document.forms["assignTo"]["Number"].value;
    if (nl == "") {
        //if(document.getElementById("ExerciseTime1").value=="") {
        errmessage += "*Please enter the number of time for leg <br>";
    }
    if (na != "" && nl == "") {
        document.assignTo.submit();
        alert('Exercise has been assigned succesfully.');
    } else if (na == "" && nl != "") {
        document.assignTo.submit();
        alert('Exercise has been assigned succesfully.');
    } else if (na != "" && nl != "") {
        document.assignTo.submit();
        alert('Exercise has been assigned succesfully.');
    } else if (errmessage.length > 0) {
        errmessage = errmessage.fontcolor("red");
        errmessage = errmessage.fontsize("2");
        document.getElementById("divMessage").innerHTML = errmessage;
    }
}
```

assignTo.jsp

```
String[] id = request.getParameterValues("assignchkbox");
String armID = request.getParameter("ArmID");
String number = request.getParameter("Number");
int count = 0;
Connection conn = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    // Step 2: Define Connection URL
    String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medicloud?user=root&password=root";
    // Step 3: Establish connection to URL
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

    if (id != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {

            String sqlStr = "Insert into assign(ArmID,Number) Value(?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
            pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id[i]));
            pstmt.setString(2, number);
            //pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(ids[i]));
            int rec = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            if (rec == 1) {
                count++;
                response.sendRedirect("assign.jsp");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Ignore the id all those in the jsp folder (They are working the way I wanted). The only problem now is that the textbox value doesnt get inserted into the database and Idk where is the error

Comment: try block gives an exception? have you printed the error in the catch block? what does it say?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala it didn't say any error o.o

Comment: Does the `form` submits successfully? print a value and see whether the jsp page get called at all

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala How do I do that? Can you help me out? I'm pretty new to this...

Comment: Just add `System.out.println("OK");` at the top of your jsp page and run the app. If _OK_ prints in your server log/console it's working

Comment: it printed out "OK" at the end of my console. @RoshanaPitigala

Answer (score 0):

Try if your jsp file accepted your needed value from form:

```
String username = "<your username>";
String pass = "<your pass>";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:<port>/medicloud";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL,username,pass);
```

Instead of your code.
In some situation, you have to import your mysqljdbc.jar into WEB-INF/lib, I don't exactly remember the path, check it in your project.

Don't forget to prove your database instance port, in mysql it should be 3306.

And your code is not clean at all, you should catch the exception to retrieve more information which needed for debugging purpose.